# Separate numeric & character data using SQL Server 2005 query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to separate my data in column, my data is

```
column1
1.1.1 Eastern express highway
1.1.2 weater way
2.1 water
2.1.2 land
2.2 sand
```

My output should be

```
column1      column2       column3
1.1            1           Eastern express highway
1.1            2            weater way
2.1            0            water
2.1            2            land
2.2            0            sand
```

Comment: Can you alter the scema to have a more useful table to start with?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(ProductDescription, 1,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) - 1
    ) AS Field1,
    SUBSTRING(ProductDescription,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription,
            CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3
        ) - (CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3)
    ) AS Field2,
    SUBSTRING(ProductDescription,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription,
            CHARINDEX(' - ', ProductDescription) + 3) + 3,
        LEN(ProductDescription)
    ) AS Field3,
    ProductDescription
FROM your_table
```

Comment: m getting error as "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function."

Comment: please add proper length of string.

Comment: SELECT
    SUBSTRING(vProjectName, 1, CHARINDEX('. ', vProjectName) - 1 ) AS Field1
    SUBSTRING(vProjectName, CHARINDEX(' . ', vProjectName) + 3, CHARINDEX(' . ', vProjectName, CHARINDEX(' . ', vProjectName) + 3 ) - (CHARINDEX(' . ', vProjectName) + 3) ) AS Field2
    SUBSTRING(vProjectName, CHARINDEX(' . ', vProjectName),CHARINDEX(' . ', vProjectName) + 3) + 3, LEN(vProjectName)) AS Field3,
    vProjectName
FROM Projects

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do it this way but this works for your sample. Try

```
SELECT
  substring(section,1,3) as column1,
  CASE WHEN LEN(section)<5 THEN '0'
  ELSE
     SUBSTRING(section,5,1)
  END as column2
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: c basically i am having sum field which dont have any number i.e "date mind" so date mind should be in 3rd column & 1st & 2nd column should be null or 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  substring(column1,1,3) as column1,
  CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',RTRIM(SUBSTRING(column1,4,7)))=0 THEN '0'
  ELSE
     SUBSTRING(column1,5,1)
  END as column2,
    --RTRIM(SUBSTRING(column1,7,43))as column3
  CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',RTRIM(SUBSTRING(column1,4,7)))!=0 
  THEN RTRIM(SUBSTRING(column1,7,43))
  ELSE
     RTRIM(SUBSTRING(column1,5,43))
  END as column3
FROM MyTable
```